# Replacing all jpg/pngs in a big folder with subfolders

Tags: c#

So hey i was searching a bit but i only found codes like

```
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(_folder, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
       .Where(s => s.EndsWith(".jpg") || s.EndsWith(".png"));
```

this is no use for me, haven't done anything like this before so hey lets try it, just need a hint to start with.
I have one big ass folder(60gb(its .mp3 + png/jpg)) lets say its name is images
in this folder, there are many other subfolders, which contains always one .jpg or .png and i would like to replace all jpgs/pngs to one i have prepared for this action, anyone got ideas?

once again:

images - folderwithjpg,folderwithjpg1,folderwithjpg2,folderwithpng
the program should search for all folders and then for each folder just check if there are any .jpg or .png and if there are any, replace them with one exact image.

if anyone wonders, its for game named osu! - there is song background for each song and i want to change it and have one the same every map.
thanks.

Comment: _"replace all jpgs/pngs to one i have prepared for this action"_ - You want to replace **every** jpg and png file with whatever file you have in mind?

Comment: yes, there is X amount of jpg/pngs and i want to replace every of them with my file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles("root folder path", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            .Where(s => s.EndsWith(".jpg") || s.EndsWith(".png"));

        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            File.Copy("path to your file", file, true);
        }
```

Comment: EndsWith wouldn't work as is. If you want to use it, then you need something like: s.ToLower().EndsWith(".jpg")

Comment: Yep, you are right, but it's better to use .ToUpperInvariant().EndsWith(".JPG")

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of all the jpg and png files starting from a root folder like this:

```
var baseFolder = @"c:\My Source Folder\Images";

var jpg = Directory.EnumerateFiles(baseFolder, "*.jpg", SearchOption.AllDirectories );
var png = Directory.EnumerateFiles(baseFolder, "*.png", SearchOption.AllDirectories );

foreach(var file in jpg) {File.Copy("< your one image path and name", file, true};
foreach(var file in png) {File.Copy("< your one image path and name", file, true};
```

PS: I am not really sure of the purpose of such an operation.

Comment: You're definitely on the right track here. Only thing that's missing is perhaps a `File.Replace` to actually do the replacement. I would suggest using `Directory.EnumerateFiles` instead of `GetFiles` because GetFiles will block until it has fetched the complete list of all matching files. EnumerateFiles allows you to start working the millisecond you get the first filename.

Comment: Sorry, my original comment came out a bit hostile - your answer is valid, I did not mean to say it isn't.

Comment: I edited it as per your comment :) Still a weird request to replace all those fiels with a single content (pure redundancy:)

Comment: If you want to go even further, you could use `Enumerable.Concat` to concatenate the two IEnumerables together so two foreach loops won't be needed. e.g. `foreach (var file in jpg.Concat(png))`. ;)

Comment: OP updated his question with the explanation - it's for a game. The game has a load of levels which use a certain image as the background. He wants to have one background image for all levels. I imagine that this isn't implemented in the game itself so a hacky approach like this is required.